# What causes the scancode offset when using setkeycodes?

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, xorg, keymap

I tried to map scancode `ffa000f1` to keycode `198` using `setkeycodes`:

```
$ sudo setkeycodes ffa000f1 198
setkeycodes: failed to set scancode ff9f2171 to keycode 198: ioctl KDSETKEYCODE: Invalid argument
```

What causes the offset (`0xffa000f1 - 0xff9f2171 = 0xDF80 = 57216`) between the scancode I provided as a parameter to `setkeycodes` (`0xffa000f1`) and the scancode mentioned in the error message (`0xff9f2171`)?